# LOCAL images in IntelliSense in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, intellisense, jsdoc

I'm using TypeScript in VS Code.  I'm using JSDoc for my comments, so IntelliSense often displays the comments as a tooltip.  And I'm using Markdown to format those comments, including images.  Mostly it works, but there's one problem.  I only see images from an HTTP server.  It will **not** display **images** from the **local file** system.

This is what I'd expect to see.
[image: this is what I'd expect]
However, this only works if I store the image on a web server.

This is what I see when I try to access a local file.
[image: Includes Broken Image]

Here's a short version of the code behind those pictures.  You can find the exact code, in context, [here](https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/penrose-tiling/commit/4465a6c897e522233b14f84ae49d7da1f36181f3#diff-67b2a098464dacb24eea37bcb390c2de667f698429bc16881adbaabe6dbdb814).

```
class IntelliSenseTest {
  /**
   * `to` and `from` assume that we are moving around the shape counter-clockwise,
   * i.e. the mathematically positive direction.
   * ![explanation of dots](./kite-dart-dots.png)
   */
  constructor(
  ) {}
}

export class Segment {
    /**
     * `to` and `from` assume that we are moving around the shape counter-clockwise,
     * i.e. the mathematically positive direction.
     * ![explanation of dots](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/penrose-tiling/master/docs/kite-dart-dots.png)
     */
    constructor(
    ) {}
    //..
  }
```

The first example is the broken one.  The second one displays the image properly but it uses a nasty workaround.  I want to be able to save the image and the source file in the same directory.  I want to be able to include them in the same commit.  Is that possible?

Note:  VS Code is able to display this file in its own window.
And I can link directly to this local file in README.md.
And we are looking at the exact same image, I just pushed my project to github.

You can see from this image or from [github](https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/penrose-tiling/tree/4465a6c897e522233b14f84ae49d7da1f36181f3/docs) that the `*.png` and `*.ts` files are in the same directory.
[image: VS code file list]

**Has anyone made this feature work?**
Any idea why it's not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have just written a Visual Studio code plugin to address your question.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgiesen.image-comments&ssr=false#overview

My plugin allows you to insert a local image path that will be displayed in the tooltip.